# MonoTouch status bar and EAGLView size

Tags: xamarin.ios

In my app, I want the status bar visible using transparent black. I want my framebuffer to be the same size as the device's screen, and I want touch input at (0,0) to be at the top-left corner of the DEVICE, not right under the status bar.

As it is now, EAGLView is initializing the framebuffer to 320x460, so I can't draw anything for the status bar to be transparent over. Also, if the user taps the top-left of the screen, the touch position is given to me as (0,-20), whereas I want (0,0).

My questions are:

**1.** What's the right way to make EAGLView initialize the framebuffer to the full device screen size?

**2.** Why is my input offset so (0,0) is under the status bar? How do I fix it?

What I'm doing now is forcing Layer.Bounds to 320x480 in ConfigureLayer. That gets the framebuffer to be the right size, but if I set EAGLView.Bounds or EAGLView.Layer.Bounds to anything, it gets reset to 320x460 constantly.

Answer (score 0):

The fix here was to set ViewController.WantsFullScreenLayout = true. Without that set, it keeps auto-resizing the view to sit under the status bar.